# How do I handle the issue of having no internet for my application?

Tags: android, error-handling, connection, google-maps-android-api-2

My application requires the internet to retrieve data from my database. Also, it uses Google Maps as the main activity. I found that whenever I test it with no internet connection, the screen goes black and then it just crashes. How should I handle this in my code when I have no internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.......

```
public boolean isNet()
 {
     boolean status=false;
     String line;
     try
     {
         URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
         while(( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
         {
         }
         status=true;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ex in isNet : "+ex.toString());
        if(ex.toString().equals("java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com"))
            status=false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return status;
 }


if(status==true)
            {
            //Do your operation
            }
            else
                show("No Internet Connection.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for internet connection:

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
    //Getting the ConnectivityManager.
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    //Getting NetworkInfo from the Connectivity manager.
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    //If I received an info and isConnectedOrConnecting return true then there is an Internet connection.
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and present a message for user if internet connection is not available.

Comment: And when there is no internet what should I do?

Comment: what can you do? if your application based on the connection to the DB there is not much you could do. just wait for the connection to get back up again.

Comment: Is there no way to degrade gracefully instead of just letting it crash =S ?

Comment: but basicly you should edit the place where you make you http request and use this method before you make that request if there is internet connection keep going with the request, if not present a message to the user.

Comment: The above code doesn't say if there's a working connection. Only if it's connected to some sort of network, but not if it's working.

Comment: chrkad, how would I check for a working connection? I have implemented the above code and I turned off Wifi and now it's using the normal mobile internet. However, it crashes everytime Wifi isn't on. Surely my app should not be crashing because the connection is slow?

Comment: I would put my check as soon as possible in the app and let the user know it requires Internet and then close. But there's also other scenarios to take into account, for example how to handle changes of network state while running the app, so this issue is a bit complicated.

Comment: This page might give you some tips for writing a BroadcastReceiver that will handle connection state changes: http://thiranjith.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/